# Passing props down to child inside parent's constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a parent's state down into a grandchild's props. The thing is, I am creating the grandchild component in the child's constructor/state variable, and it doesn't seem to want to pass the props down. The child successfully receives the props `results` object, but the grandchild has an empty object when I reference `this.props.results`. **How can I send the props down to the grandchild?**

## Parent Component

```
render()
{

    return( <ChildComponent results={this.state.results}/> );

}
```

## Child Component

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {

      containerContent: [
        <GrandChildComponent results={props.results}/>, //this.props.results also does not work
      ]

    }
  }

render()
{

<main>

   {this.state.containerContent[0]}

</main>

}
```

## Grandchild Component

```
render()
{

    <h3>{this.props.results.someValue}</h3> //Throws an error, saying `results` is empty.

}
```

Comment: Consider the fact that the constructor will only be run once. Also can you show your render function for child component

Comment: Sure -- I added my render method for the child (a simplified version). Basically, I have an array of 6 different 'views' that I render based on the state of the child. In this case I hard-coded it to be view 0, since there's only one element in the `containerContent` array.

Comment: Are your props coming from parent changing over time? Is the results object empty at some point and then getting filled later?

Comment: Yes -- you are right... they are. So I guess the constructor is only called once, as you mentioned, not once each time it is rendered? I will have to think of a different solution to display my views.

Comment: Can you not put them inside render? That will be called once the props are changed

Comment: Yes I just thought of doing the same thing! Sorry, I am new to React, still feeling my way around :-)

Comment: How is the state changed in the parent component? Apparently, the `results` are `undefined` at some point, but your grandchild expects them to always be an array. (The issue with not updating state on props change notwithstanding).

Comment: I fixed it (with @TusharShahi help)... Indeed the state of the parent was being updated, and thus I needed to send the props down in render() instead of in the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

You can use context api or else use redux.
which is more convenient.